# Unable to install libclang on 20.04 LTS

Tags: package-management, software-installation, kubuntu, error-handling, clang

After trying to install libclang-dev with `sudo apt-get install -y libclang-dev` i receive this error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libclang-dev : Depends: libclang-10-dev (>= 10~) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

When I try the [solution](https://apt.llvm.org/):

```
 $ wget https://apt.llvm.org/llvm.sh
 $ chmod +x llvm.sh
 $ sudo ./llvm.sh 12
```

Thiss occurs:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 clang-12 : Depends: libclang-common-12-dev (= 1:12.0.1~++20210511012537+24535af52ae1-1~exp1~20210510233243.87) but it is not going to be installed
 clangd-12 : Depends: libclang-common-12-dev (= 1:12.0.1~++20210511012537+24535af52ae1-1~exp1~20210510233243.87) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

The output of `sudo apt-cache policy libc6`

```
libc6:
  Installed: 2.31-0ubuntu9.2
  Candidate: 2.31-0ubuntu9.2
  Version table:
 *** 2.31-0ubuntu9.2 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.31-0ubuntu9 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: You seem to have two (almost) completely separate issues: 1) You have broken clang-10 by adding non-Ubuntu sources and packages. Remove them. 2) You have tried to bolt new clang-12 packages onto an older 20.04 system. That doesn't work. Pick between clang-10 and clang-12, use the correct release of Ubuntu for that version of Clang, and stick to the Ubuntu repositories that are built for that version of Clang.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I restore the default repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories)

Comment: Also please note that llvm 12  installs normally on fresh 20.04 LTS VM using your script. So you have to fix official repositories first. Please add output of `apt-cache policy libc6 llvm clang` to the question.

Comment: @N0rbert Can you be more specific with fixing official repositories? My sources.list file is as here https://gist.github.com/ishad0w/788555191c7037e249a439542c53e170

Comment: What about other sources located within /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ ?

Comment: Please share the output of above requested command `apt-cache policy libc6 llvm clang` and `grep "^deb\ " -r /etc/apt/ --include=*.list` . If long - use pastebin.

Comment: @user535733 google-chrome.list, team.list, vscode.list with .save files

Comment: @N0rbert
So the output for cache policy command is: https://pastebin.com/E73k8PuZ.
For next one is: https://pastebin.com/WwWDGqUV

Comment: @N0rbert Seems like I don't have llvm and clang installed at all?

Comment: @user535733 The package "libc6" is probably broken:
The following packages have unmet dependencies: libc6-i386 : Depends: libc6 (= 2.31-0ubuntu9.2) but 2.31-0ubuntu9.3 is to be installed. How to manage that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to revert libc6 library to the normal version using command below:

```
sudo apt-get install libc6=2.31-0ubuntu9.2 libc6:i386=2.31-0ubuntu9.2
```

Comment: The libllvm10 should be reverted to previous version  1:10.0.0-4ubuntu1?

Comment: Not sure, on my system `https://apt.llvm.org/llvm.sh` script installed LLVM 12 correctly. Run `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` to get newest dependencies installed.

Comment: if you have `cuda` installed this is going to ruin your day

Answer (score 3):

For me it solved

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install
sudo apt-get update
```

And then installing with

```
sudo dpkg -i rstudio-specific-version.deb
```

Answer (score 2):

I got same problem.
I have run this steps (no idea what they did - I'm new on this, but works for me)

```
sudo apt-get autoremove

sudo apt-get autoclean

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get -f install
```

Answer (score -1):

I was getting this message:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  clang : Depends: clang-10 (>= 10~) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I solved my issue with [this solution](https://copyprogramming.com/howto/how-to-install-clang-10-on-ubuntu-20-4) (formatting my own):

> When I did  `sudo aptitude install clang`, I got the same message as shown, but then typed `n`. `aptitude` then offers another solution, which is to offer to downgrade to `gcc` 9. Allow it to do that, and let it return to the command prompt. Then then do `sudo apt install clang` and you'll get `clang-10.`